# Bootstrap for ManageLogins page not working right in MVC 5

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with "ManageLogins" page. Bootstrap doesn't display ALL the external buttons (Facebook and Google). If I log in via FB, bootstrap button for FB is no longer there. It shows the word "Facebook" only. However,  bootstrap button for Google is shown fine. And if I log in via Google, the bootstrap button for Google is no longer there. It shows the word "Google" only. However, bootstrap button for Facebook is shown fine.

Below is the code for displaying the external login buttons:

```
if (Model.OtherLogins.Count > 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LinkLogin", "Manage"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
            <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in Model.OtherLogins)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-social btn-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">
                        <i class="fa fa-@p.AuthenticationType.ToLower()"></i>@p.AuthenticationType
                    </button>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    }
}
```